# asp.net store URL of 404 request

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-status-code-404

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/error/1" mode="Off" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error redirect="/404.aspx" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

AND

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

**404.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class _404
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    MyBase.Render(writer)
    Response.StatusCode = 404
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim lang As String = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName

    GlobalFunctions.ReportError("404 URL", Request.UrlReferrer.Host.ToString)


End Sub
End Class
```

in the code-behind of my 404.aspx I'd like to store which URL was requested in the first place. How can I do so?
If it's not possible in the 404.aspx.vb I'd like to know how else I can store the request in my DB.

Thanks!

Comment: use the HTTPReffererproperty of the request object, or get the respective header value from the request.

Comment: Thanks. May I suggest next time you add an answer instead of a comment, that way you also get rewarded for your effort :)
ps. it's not solved yet and I added a new comment with the answer below, if you could have a look at that?

Comment: Thanks @Floran, but actually my comment was added to guide you just, so you can investigate the answer by yourself, if I write something concrete that solves your problem, i shall surely add it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Request.UrlReferrer Gets information about the URL of the client's previous request that linked to the current URL.

Directly from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

Comment: I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.ToString. Also for .OriginalString and .Host? Why? I updated my original post with code for 404.aspx.vb

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` property may not always contain a value (e.g. in case of crawlers/bots) so you need to check for null before accessing it.

Comment: The error occurs when I myself fill in the non-existing page in my browser address bar..so no bots/crawlers would be present.